# JQuery: How to select window and some other divs by id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector

I have a context menu that pops up whenever a click happens at a certain div inside a container and I want it to hide if either the window element or its container is scrolled.
How can I add the 'window' element in there?

```
$("#tree-container").scroll(function(){
    $cxtMenu.hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your question, try:

```
$("#tree-container").add(window).scroll(function(){
    $cxtMenu.hide();
});
```

If not, please consider to provide a jsFiddle which replicates your issue

Answer (score 0):

You can add a scroll handler directly to the window like

```
$( window ).scroll(function() {
     //Do stuff
});
```

(Per "Example: To do something when your page is scrolled" of http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)